# Query took 50ms on pg11 but 500ms on pg12

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Here is a [request with its plan](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/784c76f39ec48bd2). The request goal is to list a table structure: indexes, foreign keys, columns.

This request is fast with postgres 11 (50ms), and slow on postgres 12 (500ms). How is it possible that pg12 be x10 times slower than pg11 for this request?

Request code:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT
            "tableConstraints".constraint_name AS "constraintName",
            "tableConstraints".table_name AS "tableName",
            "tableConstraints".constraint_type AS "columnType",
            "keyColumnUsage".column_name AS "columnName",
            "constraintColumnUsage".table_name AS "foreignTableName",
            "constraintColumnUsage".column_name AS "foreignColumnName",
            json_agg("uidx"."uniqueIndexes") filter (where "uidx"."uniqueIndexes" is not null) AS "uniqueIndexes"
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS "tableConstraints"
          JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS "keyColumnUsage"
            ON "tableConstraints".constraint_name = "keyColumnUsage".constraint_name
          JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS "constraintColumnUsage"
            ON "constraintColumnUsage".constraint_name = "tableConstraints".constraint_name
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
            -- Get the index name, table name and list of columns of the unique indexes of a table
            SELECT
              pg_index.indexrelid::regclass AS "indexName",
              "pgClass1".relname AS "tableName",
              json_agg(DISTINCT pg_attribute.attname) AS "uniqueIndexes"
            FROM
              pg_class AS "pgClass1",
              pg_class AS "pgClass2",
              pg_index,
              pg_attribute
            WHERE "pgClass1".relname = 'projects'
              AND "pgClass1".oid = pg_index.indrelid
              AND "pgClass2".oid = pg_index.indexrelid
              AND pg_attribute.attrelid = "pgClass1".oid
              AND pg_attribute.attnum = ANY(pg_index.indkey)
              AND not pg_index.indisprimary
              AND pg_index.indisunique
              AND "pgClass1".relkind = 'r'
              AND not "pgClass1".relname like 'pg%'
              GROUP BY
                "tableName",
                "indexName"
          ) AS "uidx"
            ON "uidx"."tableName" = "tableConstraints".table_name
          WHERE "uidx"."tableName" = 'projects'
            OR "tableConstraints".table_name = 'projects'
          GROUP BY
            "constraintName",
            "tableConstraints".table_name,
            "columnType",
            "columnName",
            "foreignTableName",
            "foreignColumnName"
```

Here is the start of the plan, which is too long for the message:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=380.04..380.05 rows=1 width=384) (actual time=194.087..194.124 rows=4 loops=1)
"  Group Key: ""*SELECT* 1"".constraint_name, ""*SELECT* 1"".table_name, ""*SELECT* 1"".constraint_type, ((a.attname)::information_schema.sql_identifier), ((""*SELECT* 1_1"".relname)::information_schema.sql_identifier), ((""*SELECT* 1_1"".attname)::information_schema.sql_identifier)"
  Buffers: shared hit=41399 read=36
  I/O Timings: read=0.270
  ->  Sort  (cost=380.04..380.05 rows=1 width=384) (actual time=194.072..194.103 rows=12 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: ""*SELECT* 1"".constraint_name, ""*SELECT* 1"".table_name, ""*SELECT* 1"".constraint_type, ((a.attname)::information_schema.sql_identifier), ((""*SELECT* 1_1"".relname)::information_schema.sql_identifier), ((""*SELECT* 1_1"".attname)::information_schema.sql_identifier)"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 31kB
        Buffers: shared hit=41399 read=36
        I/O Timings: read=0.270
        ->  Hash Full Join  (cost=140.09..380.04 rows=1 width=384) (actual time=44.129..194.040 rows=12 loops=1)
"              Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".table_name)::name = uidx.""tableName"")"
"              Filter: ((uidx.""tableName"" = 'projects'::name) OR ((""*SELECT* 1"".table_name)::name = 'projects'::name))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 110
              Buffers: shared hit=41393 read=36
              I/O Timings: read=0.270
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=129.73..369.69 rows=1 width=352) (actual time=5.651..193.250 rows=114 loops=1)
"                    Join Filter: (c.conname = (""*SELECT* 1"".constraint_name)::name)"
                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 35454
                    Buffers: shared hit=41310 read=36
                    I/O Timings: read=0.270
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=102.68..195.28 rows=1 width=320) (actual time=3.427..7.064 rows=114 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=2369 read=17
                          I/O Timings: read=0.138
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=102.62..194.97 rows=4 width=296) (actual time=3.411..6.310 rows=114 loops=1)
"                                Hash Cond: (c.conname = ""*SELECT* 1_1"".conname)"
                                Buffers: shared hit=2027 read=17
                                I/O Timings: read=0.138
                                ->  ProjectSet  (cost=24.55..56.88 rows=16000 width=341) (actual time=0.840..3.580 rows=110 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=290 read=2
                                      I/O Timings: read=0.030
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=24.55..32.06 rows=16 width=95) (actual time=0.391..1.097 rows=108 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=253
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=24.53..31.18 rows=16 width=99) (actual time=0.378..0.657 rows=108 loops=1)
                                                  Hash Cond: (r.relnamespace = nr.oid)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=36
                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.49..30.12 rows=24 width=103) (actual time=0.239..0.452 rows=108 loops=1)
                                                        Hash Cond: (c.conrelid = r.oid)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=27
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on pg_constraint c  (cost=0.00..6.55 rows=141 width=95) (actual time=0.012..0.114 rows=108 loops=1)
"                                                              Filter: (contype = ANY ('{p,u,f}'::""char""[]))"
                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 10
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=6
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=23.12..23.12 rows=105 width=12) (actual time=0.205..0.206 rows=108 loops=1)
                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=21
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on pg_class r  (cost=0.00..23.12 rows=105 width=12) (actual time=0.008..0.185 rows=108 loops=1)
"                                                                    Filter: (relkind = ANY ('{r,p}'::""char""[]))"
                                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 512
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=21
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.123..0.124 rows=5 loops=1)
                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=9
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace nr  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.047..0.104 rows=5 loops=1)
                                                              Filter: (NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(oid))
                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=9
                                            ->  Index Only Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nc  (cost=0.03..0.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=108)
                                                  Index Cond: (oid = c.connamespace)
                                                  Heap Fetches: 108
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=217
                                ->  Hash  (cost=78.06..78.06 rows=4 width=192) (actual time=2.550..2.565 rows=124 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 36kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1737 read=15
                                      I/O Timings: read=0.108
                                      ->  Append  (cost=34.79..78.06 rows=4 width=192) (actual time=0.522..2.503 rows=124 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=1737 read=15
                                            I/O Timings: read=0.108
"                                            ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 1_1""  (cost=34.79..34.79 rows=1 width=192) (actual time=0.521..0.538 rows=14 loops=1)"
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=281 read=10
                                                  I/O Timings: read=0.071
                                                  ->  Unique  (cost=34.79..34.79 rows=1 width=324) (actual time=0.520..0.534 rows=14 loops=1)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=281 read=10
                                                        I/O Timings: read=0.071
                                                        ->  Sort  (cost=34.79..34.79 rows=1 width=324) (actual time=0.519..0.526 rows=28 loops=1)
"                                                              Sort Key: nr_1.nspname, r_1.relname, r_1.relowner, a_1.attname, nc_1.nspname, c_1.conname"
                                                              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 39kB
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=281 read=10
                                                              I/O Timings: read=0.071
                                                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.20..34.78 rows=1 width=324) (actual time=0.178..0.489 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                    Join Filter: (c_1.connamespace = nc_1.oid)
                                                                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 140
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=281 read=10
                                                                    I/O Timings: read=0.071
                                                                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.20..33.74 rows=1 width=264) (actual time=0.173..0.431 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=253 read=10
                                                                          I/O Timings: read=0.071
                                                                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.17..33.49 rows=1 width=204) (actual time=0.163..0.394 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=197 read=10
                                                                                I/O Timings: read=0.071
                                                                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.11..33.42 rows=1 width=140) (actual time=0.154..0.336 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=113 read=10
                                                                                      I/O Timings: read=0.071
                                                                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.06..30.91 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.103..0.216 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=27 read=9
                                                                                            I/O Timings: read=0.061
                                                                                            ->  Seq Scan on pg_constraint c_1  (cost=0.00..6.51 rows=6 width=72) (actual time=0.008..0.045 rows=10 loops=1)
"                                                                                                  Filter: (contype = 'c'::""char"")"
                                                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 108
                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=6
                                                                                            ->  Index Scan using pg_depend_depender_index on pg_depend d  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=3 loops=10)
                                                                                                  Index Cond: ((classid = '2606'::oid) AND (objid = c_1.oid))
                                                                                                  Filter: (refclassid = '1259'::oid)
                                                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=21 read=9
                                                                                                  I/O Timings: read=0.061
                                                                                      ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a_1  (cost=0.06..2.51 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=28)
                                                                                            Index Cond: ((attrelid = d.refobjid) AND (attnum = d.refobjsubid))
                                                                                            Filter: (NOT attisdropped)
                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=86 read=1
                                                                                            I/O Timings: read=0.010
                                                                                ->  Index Scan using pg_class_oid_index on pg_class r_1  (cost=0.06..0.07 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=28)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (oid = a_1.attrelid)
"                                                                                      Filter: ((relkind = ANY ('{r,p}'::""char""[])) AND pg_has_role(relowner, 'USAGE'::text))"
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=84
                                                                          ->  Index Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nr_1  (cost=0.03..0.20 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=28)
                                                                                Index Cond: (oid = r_1.relnamespace)
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=56
                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace nc_1  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=6 width=68) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=6 loops=28)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=28
"                                            ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 2_1""  (cost=23.66..43.26 rows=3 width=192) (actual time=0.315..1.950 rows=110 loops=1)"
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1456 read=5
                                                  I/O Timings: read=0.038
                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.66..43.25 rows=3 width=324) (actual time=0.314..1.935 rows=110 loops=1)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1456 read=5
                                                        I/O Timings: read=0.038
                                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.63..43.06 rows=3 width=196) (actual time=0.303..1.819 rows=110 loops=1)
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1235 read=5
                                                              I/O Timings: read=0.038
                                                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.61..42.59 rows=3 width=200) (actual time=0.291..1.628 rows=110 loops=1)
                                                                    Join Filter: (r_2.oid = a_2.attrelid)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=1014 read=5
                                                                    I/O Timings: read=0.038
                                                                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.55..30.18 rows=8 width=195) (actual time=0.249..0.318 rows=108 loops=1)
"                                                                          Hash Cond: (CASE c_2.contype WHEN 'f'::""char"" THEN c_2.confrelid ELSE c_2.conrelid END = r_2.oid)"
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=46
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on pg_constraint c_2  (cost=0.00..6.55 rows=141 width=123) (actual time=0.004..0.031 rows=108 loops=1)
"                                                                                Filter: (contype = ANY ('{p,u,f}'::""char""[]))"
                                                                                Rows Removed by Filter: 10
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=6
                                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=23.43..23.43 rows=35 width=72) (actual time=0.224..0.225 rows=38 loops=1)
                                                                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=40
                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on pg_class r_2  (cost=0.00..23.43 rows=35 width=72) (actual time=0.072..0.214 rows=38 loops=1)
"                                                                                      Filter: ((relkind = ANY ('{r,p}'::""char""[])) AND pg_has_role(relowner, 'USAGE'::text))"
                                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 582
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=40
                                                                    ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a_2  (cost=0.06..1.55 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.005..0.012 rows=1 loops=108)
"                                                                          Index Cond: (attrelid = CASE c_2.contype WHEN 'f'::""char"" THEN c_2.confrelid ELSE c_2.conrelid END)"
"                                                                          Filter: ((NOT attisdropped) AND (attnum = ANY (CASE c_2.contype WHEN 'f'::""char"" THEN c_2.confkey ELSE c_2.conkey END)))"
                                                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 25
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=968 read=5
                                                                          I/O Timings: read=0.038
                                                              ->  Index Only Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nr_2  (cost=0.03..0.15 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=110)
                                                                    Index Cond: (oid = r_2.relnamespace)
                                                                    Heap Fetches: 110
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=221
                                                        ->  Index Only Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nc_2  (cost=0.03..0.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=110)
                                                              Index Cond: (oid = c_2.connamespace)
                                                              Heap Fetches: 110
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=221
                          ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a  (cost=0.06..0.08 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=114)
                                Index Cond: ((attrelid = r.oid) AND (attnum = ((information_schema._pg_expandarray(c.conkey))).x))
"                                Filter: ((NOT attisdropped) AND (pg_has_role(r.relowner, 'USAGE'::text) OR has_column_privilege(r.oid, attnum, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES'::text)))"
                                Buffers: shared hit=342
                    ->  Append  (cost=27.05..173.97 rows=124 width=160) (actual time=0.072..1.605 rows=312 loops=114)
                          Buffers: shared hit=38941 read=19
                          I/O Timings: read=0.132
"                          ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 1""  (cost=27.05..35.65 rows=12 width=160) (actual time=0.072..0.317 rows=116 loops=114)"
                                Buffers: shared hit=28556 read=8
                                I/O Timings: read=0.062
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=27.05..35.61 rows=12 width=512) (actual time=0.072..0.305 rows=116 loops=114)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=28556 read=8
                                      I/O Timings: read=0.062
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=27.03..34.94 rows=12 width=133) (actual time=0.069..0.195 rows=116 loops=114)
                                            Join Filter: (r_3.relnamespace = nr_3.oid)
                                            Rows Removed by Join Filter: 464
                                            Buffers: shared hit=2107 read=8
                                            I/O Timings: read=0.062
                                            ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace nr_3  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=5 loops=114)
                                                  Filter: (NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(oid))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=114
                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=27.03..33.64 rows=18 width=137) (actual time=0.004..0.010 rows=116 loops=570)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1993 read=8
                                                  I/O Timings: read=0.062
                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=27.03..33.62 rows=18 width=137) (actual time=2.042..2.092 rows=116 loops=1)
                                                        Hash Cond: (c_3.conrelid = r_3.oid)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1993 read=8
                                                        I/O Timings: read=0.062
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on pg_constraint c_3  (cost=0.00..6.51 rows=147 width=73) (actual time=0.005..0.031 rows=118 loops=1)
"                                                              Filter: (contype <> ALL ('{t,x}'::""char""[]))"
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=6
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=26.77..26.77 rows=74 width=72) (actual time=2.006..2.007 rows=38 loops=1)
                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1987 read=8
                                                              I/O Timings: read=0.062
                                                              -
[content dropped]

                                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.20..10.34 rows=1 width=132) (actual time=0.506..0.599 rows=3 loops=1)
    "                                            Join Filter: (""pgClass1"".oid = pg_attribute.attrelid)"
                                                Buffers: shared hit=80
                                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..9.13 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.054..0.071 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                      Buffers: shared hit=17
                                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.08..9.02 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.039..0.046 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                            Buffers: shared hit=7
    "                                                        ->  Index Scan using pg_class_relname_nsp_index on pg_class ""pgClass1""  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)"
                                                                  Index Cond: (relname = 'projects'::name)
    "                                                              Filter: ((relname !~~ 'pg%'::text) AND (relkind = 'r'::""char""))"
                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                            ->  Index Scan using pg_index_indrelid_index on pg_index  (cost=0.03..4.96 rows=1 width=35) (actual time=0.024..0.028 rows=3 loops=1)
    "                                                              Index Cond: (indrelid = ""pgClass1"".oid)"
                                                                  Filter: ((NOT indisprimary) AND indisunique)
                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 4
                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=4
    "                                                  ->  Index Only Scan using pg_class_oid_index on pg_class ""pgClass2""  (cost=0.06..0.10 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=3)"
                                                            Index Cond: (oid = pg_index.indexrelid)
                                                            Heap Fetches: 3
                                                            Buffers: shared hit=10
                                                ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute  (cost=0.06..1.21 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.153..0.174 rows=1 loops=3)
                                                      Index Cond: (attrelid = pg_index.indrelid)
                                                      Filter: (attnum = ANY ((pg_index.indkey)::smallint[]))
                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 65
                                                      Buffers: shared hit=63
    Planning Time: 20.217 ms
    Execution Time: 195.657 ms
```

Comment: A question should be self-contained, not just point to a link that can become broken. We'd like to know the query and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. Not everybody can work well with Dalibo's tool.

Comment: information_schema is there for standards-compliance, not for performance.  Can you try querying the pg_catalog tables directly instead?

Comment: The plan is too large to figure in the message (>30000 chars), but the request can be run on any postgres database.

Comment: Thanks. I fail to see the simple query that your question promises. That could be a clue: try to simplify the problem until you have a minimal reproducible case. However, I can see that this can be slow: it accesses over 40000 8kB pages. If those are not cached, the query will be much slower. Try to figure out where they come from. Also, look for bad row count estimates.

Comment: "as you can see there is 4 join and a sub-select"  The sub-select alone joins 4 tables, then that is joined to 3 "tables", but each of those 3 is really a view, which in turn join many tables each.  So it is not surprising the plan is very large.  But your plan shows it taking much less than one second, certainly not 4 minutes.

Comment: yes @jjanes, I discovered later that there is not 4 joins but maybe 20, sorry for that.
Also, the duration problem is not 4 minutes but, the query took 50ms on postgres 11 and it took 500ms on postgres 12.
So the real question is: how is it possible for pg12 to be x10 slower than pg11?
Sorry for those mistakes, regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Slim

I'm able to reproduce your issue on a huge database I have on my end.

On pg11, your request gives me a response time of around ~50ms on a single table.
On pg12, the same request is ~500ms (x10 times!)

Looking at [the postgres 12 changelog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.0/):

> Treat object-name columns in the information_schema views as being of type name, not varchar (Tom Lane)

> Per the SQL standard, object-name columns in the information_schema views are declared as being of domain type sql_identifier. In PostgreSQL, the underlying catalog columns are really of type name. This change makes sql_identifier be a domain over name, rather than varchar as before. This eliminates a semantic mismatch in comparison and sorting behavior, which can greatly improve the performance of queries on information_schema views that restrict an object-name column. Note however that inequality restrictions, for example

> SELECT ... FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name < 'foo';
> will now use “C”-locale comparison semantics by default, rather than the database's default collation as before. Sorting on these columns will also follow “C” ordering rules. The previous behavior (and inefficiency) can be enforced by adding a COLLATE "default" clause.

Introspecting your request on my end seems to show that most of the cost of the request comes from this JOIN

```
          JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS "keyColumnUsage"
            ON "tableConstraints".constraint_name = "keyColumnUsage".constraint_name
```

I'm far from being an SQL expert, however, and following the changelog, forcing it to use default collation like so

```
          JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS "keyColumnUsage"
            ON "tableConstraints".constraint_name = "keyColumnUsage".constraint_name COLLATE DEFAULT
```

seems to give back the ~50ms I was getting with pg11.

I'm still convinced that @jjanes comment about rewriting this request to use `pg_catalog` tables instead of `information_schema` views would still be beneficial for performances matters.